# Send data to bind functions. with the structure "click: function () {...}"

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I can send data such as this (the data are different)?

```
$("div.test").bind("click", {foo: "bar1"}, function(event) { ... })
$("div.test").bind("mouseenter", {foo: "bar2"}, function(event) { ... })
$("div.test").bind("mouseleave", {foo: "bar3"}, function(event) { ... })
```

but with this structure:

```
$("div.test").bind({
  click: function(){ ... },
  mouseenter: function(){ ... },
  mouseleave: function(){ ... }
});
```

and is it also possible to send the same information, "but not before declaring a variable with the data:

not this:

```
var data = "test";
$("div.test").bind({
  click: function(){ 
   // use data
  },
  mouseenter:{ 
   // use data
  },
  mouseleave: { 
   // use data
  }
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, not what I wanted but it is useful to me:

HTML

```
<button id="test">test</button>
<div id="data-event"></div>
```

JS

```
var fn = function(event) {

    $("#data-event").append("<div>" + event.data[event.type].xx + "</div>");

};

$("#test").bind(
    {
      click:  fn,
      mouseover: fn
    },
    {click: { xx: "click-text" }, mouseover: { xx: "mouseover-text" } });
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wbbv6/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it matters, but if you just don't want it running the selector over again, you can do two things:
1) Save the object before binding:

```
var $mytest = $("div.test");
$mytest.bind("click", {foo: "bar1"}, function(event) { ... });
$mytest.bind("mouseenter", {foo: "bar2"}, function(event) { ... });
$mytest.bind("mouseleave", {foo: "bar3"}, function(event) { ... });
```

2) You could chain them:

```
$("div.test").bind("click", {foo: "bar1"}, function(event) { ... })
    .bind("mouseenter", {foo: "bar2"}, function(event) { ... })
    .bind("mouseleave", {foo: "bar3"}, function(event) { ... });
```

Is there another reason why you want to do this?

**Edit**
To explicitly answer the question, no it's not possible to pass data in without declaring it outside with the jQuery "map" object format. Unless you trigger the events manually, which I don't think is what you want to do.

Comment: This is a json structure, and very different in their use and statement

Comment: @andres descalzo - I'm aware that it's a JSON structure, but according to your example, you're doing the same thing as if you bind them with my examples above. As far as I'm aware (from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)), using the short form "map" version is the same as calling bind many times for each event.

Comment: @andres descalzo - What?  I guess I should have explicitly stated that it cannot be done. I've added that in now.

Comment: BTW, that's not a "JSON structure". JSON objects can't contain functions. It's a plain JavaScript object.